# tkinter image segfault

Tags: python, tkinter, segmentation-fault, python-imaging-library

I am creating a simple gui with an image using Tkinter and the following gives me a segmentation fault:

```
from Tkinter import*
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

window=Tk();
window.geometry("500x500")
testimg="Argentina.png"

img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(testimg))
```

From browsing other [answers](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1241) to this problem, I have figured out that the issue is that PIL is accessing frameworks from /System/Libraries/Frameworks instead of /Libraries/Frameworks. I am unsure of how to fix this issue. I'm on OSX if that's relevant.

Comment: I have done that. I renamed both Tk.framework and Tcl.framework in /System/Libraries/Frameworks and that got rid of the segfault; but then PIL couldn't find the correct directories since they were renamed. I don't know how to redirect PIL to the /Libraries/Frameworks folders (and why renaming them should do anything in the first place).

Comment: I also read somewhere that install_name_tool can be used to do this, but the man page wasn't super helpful and I couldn't find any useful examples of how this might work

Answer (score 0):

Partial resolution in [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2471) GitHub thread. The problem comes from the frameworks directories being improperly linked through Anaconda. Currently not resolvable, but Anaconda devs are aware of the issue.